# Console log of mongodb data is different from terminal and DevTools in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, google-chrome-devtools

I have node running inside a docker container and am exposing the debug port so I can connect directly.

However what I see inside the console differs from devtools.

## docker-compose.yml

```
ports:
  - 4000:4000
  - 9229:9229
```

[image]

However it will display correct in DevTools if I `console.info(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(settings)))`

How could I see the data without having to do this odd hack?

Comment: There's no other way because devtools lazily expands objects, you're using the correct "hack". A faster and better variant of such a hack is to use any "deep clone" function.

Comment: Ah nice, so I could just do a spread, ha so odd!!

Comment: Spread-cloning will work too if you don't modify deeply nested data, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Console can output only string, so basically it transforms mongodb object to string, as long as DevTools shows live data as they are.

Comment: Thanks :) but it shows as a `object` with `model: [Object]`. So I have to convert it to string and then back into an object.